# $\wedge$ in set builder notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Wikipedia says to use $\wedge$ in set-builder notation like $\{x \,:\, x > 3 \wedge x \neq 10\}$. However, I prefer to merely seperate predicates by a comma. Which notation is more common?

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.  Use $\wedge$.

Comment: Also, I would write $\{x: (x > 3)\wedge(x\not=10)\}$.

Comment: Better yet, just use the word "and". I personally find unnecessary use of notation from mathematical logic to get old very quickly. Perhaps it's just me, but it makes me feel like I'm reading *Principia Mathematica* when we're just doing ordinary algebra...

Comment: I'd just write "and", as @pjs36, besides his point, I think the wedge is the most ugly logical conective :-p.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, [the Wikipedia article I found](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) uses both:

$$
  \{ x \mid x \in \Bbb R \land x > 0 \} 
  \quad\text{and}\quad 
  \{ p/q \mid p,q \in \Bbb Z, q \neq 0 \}
$$

I would suggest the former, because of the (possible) confusion that can arise in the latter example, using the comma to signify two things:

1. Separating two or several variables that satisfy the same criterion ($p,q \in \Bbb Z$).
2. Separating two clauses.

Hence, writing

$$\{ p/q \mid p,q \in \Bbb Z \land q \neq 0 \} $$

is logically consistent with what all the predicates specify together.

Comment: I saw those exact examples on Wikipedia and then came here wondering whether the two symbols are really just synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be clear whether a comma signifies *and* or *or*. The reason it is complicated is because of the comma's use and meanings in different places: $x = 2,3$ means *or*, but $x\in \mathbb{R}, x>3$ may be *and*. So in a more ambiguous case or when your audience is unfamiliar with your notation, you should explicitly state (at least at first) what you mean, *or* use unambiguous notation.